# Access $HOME in Dockerfile ENV instruction

Tags: linux, docker, dockerfile

I'm trying to set an environment variable with ENV instruction dynamically using $HOME variable (i think its a system environment variable).

But ENV is not able to access $HOME. Its blank. Although i'm able to echo $HOME.

```
FROM somebaseimage

....
....

USER 5051

RUN echo $HOME
# prints /home/myuser

ENV MY_JSON_FILEPATH="${HOME}/my_file.json"

RUN echo $MY_JSON_FILEPATH
# prints /my_file.json
```

I have tried
"${HOME}/my_file.json", "$HOME/my_file.json"; both don't work.

What would be the best way to set such environment variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should add the line `ARG HOME` after the `FROM ...` line and pass build option [--build-arg](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options)  or add [build:args](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#args) parameter in your docker-compose file.

Answer (score 0):

In case you need that variable **just during the build**

```bash
FROM ubuntu

SHELL ["/bin/bash", "-c"]

ENV BASH_ENV="/etc/bash_env"

USER root

RUN echo "export MY_JSON_FILEPATH=$HOME/MY_JSON_FILEPATH" >>$BASH_ENV

RUN echo $MY_JSON_FILEPATH
```

```bash
#6 [3/3] RUN echo $MY_JSON_FILEPATH
#6 0.246 /root/MY_JSON_FILEPATH
#6 DONE 0.3s
```

**Reference**

- [6.2 Bash Startup Files](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Startup-Files.html)
- [Dockerfile: $HOME is set, but becomes blank when using it to define other environment variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839369/dockerfile-home-is-set-but-becomes-blank-when-using-it-to-define-other-enviro/60848005#60848005)